# Reordering HTML list items with JS

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm trying to move a list item in a standard unordered list but have no idea where to start. I can't access the HTML and only have a client JS file so guess I would have to do it through JS.

The list looks like this:

```
    <nav id="main_navigation">
    <ul class="level_1 children_9">
        <li class="level_1 first" id="1">
            <a class="level_1" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="level_1" id="2">
            <a class="level_1" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="level_1" id="3">
            <a class="level_1" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="level_1" id="4">
            <a class="level_1" href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="level_1" id="5">
            <a class="level_1" href="#">Item 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

I want to move item 4 to where item 1 is and maintain the rest of the order.

The only examples I have found involve reorder on click which is way too complicated.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: How do you want it? On page load?

Comment: On page load would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you mean something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('li.level_1');
    items[3].parentNode.insertBefore(items[3], items[0]);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cht1a64p/1/)

Comment: Yes that worked a treat. The only thing is that it takes a while for the JS to kick in and change the order. Is there a way to speed this up? Thanks Putvande!

Comment: It is waiting for the window to be loaded. Not sure what you could do about it since you can't change the HTML/.